# Updating custom card expand UI in cardslib?

Tags: android, cardslib

This isn't an issue, it's more of a question. I wanted to know when we create a card with custom expand and put that card in a cardslist. When all is the setUpInnerViewElements() called? is it called when we expand the card or is it also called when we touch the card or scroll the list?

And if I am to update the Ui of the card expand at runtime while it is expanded how would you suggest doing this ? Suppose I have button which prompts the user to enter some string and I want to append that string to an existing string in the CardExpand? and at the same time make that string available to all other other cards in their expand views ? Is there any method I override to achieve this ?

Im sorry I cant provide code because its very long and tedious piece of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setupInnerViewElements()` in an adapter, is called by the standard [`getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method inside the adapter.

It is called when the list scrolls, or when you update the adapter for example (when you expand/collapse a card, you update the adapter).

Currently you can't use different layout for the cards in the adapter.
Hovewer you can set some values inside the card (model) to enable/disable some elements in the ui (in the s`etupInnerViewElements`).

If you would like to update runtime the ui, you have to update the values inside the cards in you adapter.